# Ninject factory not working with conventions for me

Tags: c#, ninject

I am trying to use the method of binding located here but having no luck
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface 
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface%3A-Referencing-Named-Bindings

Keep in mind I am not trying to do it this way:https://gist.github.com/akimboyko/4593576
Rather I am trying to use the convention GetMercedes() to mean

I am basically trying to achieve this:https://gist.github.com/akimboyko/4593576 with conventions specified in the above examples.

```
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.Factory;
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject.Parameters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test.NinjectFactory
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            using (var kernel = new StandardKernel(new CarModule()))
            {


               var factory = kernel.Get<ICarFactory>();
               var mercedes =factory.GetMercedes();
                int i = 1; 

            }
        }

        public interface ICar
        {
            void Drive();

        }

        public class Mercedes : ICar
        {
            readonly ICarFactory carFactory;
            public Mercedes(ICarFactory carFactory)
            {
                this.carFactory = carFactory;
            }

            public void Drive()
            {
                var Mercedes = this.carFactory.GetMercedes();
            }

        }


        public interface ICarFactory
        {
            ICar GetMercedes();
        }

        public class CarModule : NinjectModule
        {
            public override void  Load()
            {
                //https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface%3A-Referencing-Named-Bindings
                Kernel.Bind<ICarFactory>().ToFactory();
                Bind<ICar>().To<Mercedes>().NamedLikeFactoryMethod<ICarFactory>(x => x.GetMercedes());//doesnt work for me

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the anwswer here:
https://gist.github.com/akimboyko/5338320

It seems you need a function to take care of the binding

```
public class BaseTypeBindingGenerator<InterfaceType> : IBindingGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        if (type != null && !type.IsAbstract && type.IsClass && typeof(InterfaceType).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            string.Format("Binds '{0}' to '{1}' as '{2}", type, type.Name, typeof(InterfaceType)).Dump();

            yield return bindingRoot.Bind(typeof(InterfaceType))
                                    .To(type)
                                    .Named(type.Name) as IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this as an answer because it is *most likely* the cause.

The factory extensions use prefixed `Get` methods as a standard. You'll run into issues by calling any of your factory methods with prefixed `Get` and using `NamedLikeFactoryMethod`. For example, `GetFord`, `GetMercedes`, `GetNissan`. You'll notice that, in the example at the link you provided, the function is called `CreateMercedes`.

Change your function name to `CreateMercedes` or **anything that doesn't start with** `Get` and it should be fine.

Comment: The goal is to use conventions like so:https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface%3A-Referencing-Named-Bindings
So that advice may not be what I am looking for. Thank you for taking the time to respond.